# Bug in code. Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors

I'm beginner in LaTeX and don't understand why I'm getting error. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 

%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
%%\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics{escudounipamplona.png}},
angle=0,
scale=0.45,
color=black,
opacity=0.1
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{M{#1}}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=75pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|M{3.0cm}|X|M{2.5cm}|M{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{4}*{\includegraphics[scale=0.034]{escudounipamplona}}
    &
    \multirow{4}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Propuesta trabajo de grado para optar por el título de Ingeniero en Mecatrónica}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{C\'odigo}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{1.2}\\
    &&&
    \\\cline{3-4}
    &&
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Pagina}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\small\emph{Pagina \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}\hspace{15pt}}\\
    &&&\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
}



\begin{document}
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{

\Large\textbf{Detecci\'on y diagnostico de fallas basados en t\'ecnicas de aprendizaje autom\'atico supervisado: aplicaci\'on al problema del benchmark DAMADICS}  
\vspace{3cm}
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar\\

\vspace{3cm}

{\normalsize \textit{Director}} \\
Dr. Rocco Tarantino Alvarado \\
{\normalsize \textit{Doctorado en Ciencias Aplicadas}} \\
\vspace{3cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{

\Large\textbf{Detecci\'on y diagnostico de fallas basados en t\'ecnicas de aprendizaje autom\'atico supervisado: aplicaci\'on al problema del benchmark DAMADICS}  
\vspace{2.5cm}
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar \\
{\normalsize \textit{Codigo: 1116249797}} \\
{\normalsize \textit{Correo electronico: judabo@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{2.5cm}
{\normalsize \textit{Director}} \\
Dr. Rocco Tarantino Alvarado \\
{\normalsize \textit{Doctorado en Ciencias Aplicadas}} 
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Correo electronico: rocco.tarantino@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{2.5cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{INTRODUCCI\'ON }
La supervisión de procesos técnicos tiene como objetivo ilustrar el estado actual del proceso, indicar estados no deseados o no permitidos y tomar acciones encaminadas a la corrección de los mismos con el fin de evitar da\n~os o accidentes \cite{isermannFaults}. Esta disciplina permite el desarrollo de metodos sistematicos que permiten la deteccion y posterior de \textbf{fallas} en plantas industriales que derivan en perdidas economicas, paro de produccion, daños en actuadores y sensores, entre otros.  

\bibliography{anteproyectoTabularX} 
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

    \end{document}
```

And this is my output log:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.33 \bibcite{\IeC {\textbullet }}{2}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 33.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 33.

! Extra \endcsname.
\@newl@bel ... \bbl@tempa \csname #1@#2\endcsname 
                                                  \def \bbl@tempb {#3}\@safe...
l.33 \bibcite{\IeC {\textbullet }}{2}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Attached a capture from Texmaker log window

[image]

Comment: Greetings from another Colombian!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had

```
da\n~os
```

and it should be

```
da\~nos
```

### Remarks

- since you are loading the `inputenc` package with `utf8` option

  ```
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  ```

  you can write accented letters, eñes and diéresis directly from the keyboard.
- You should load `hyperref` as the last package

Comment: I made those changes but I'm still receiving the same error.  By the way, thank you again Mr. Medina. Maybe there is a conflict with the packages

Comment: @jd1215 It doesn't seem to be that. Once I fixed the typo I mentioned in my answer I could process your document with no problems (of course, using a different image than the one you used). Start moving `\end{document}` upwards until the error disappears; once this has been done, you can identify the possible culprit. Report the result of your search.

Comment: @jd1215 looking at the error message that you posted, the problem might be with the bibliography. Does the problem disappear if you comment out the lines `\bibliography{anteproyectoTabularX} 
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` delete the auxiliary files and compile again?

Comment: Yes sir. You are right, the error disappears.

Comment: Do you want to take a look at the bib file?

Comment: @jd1215 So the problem is indeed there. Before looking at the `.bib` file, try this: copy paste the following code exactly as is in a fresh new file (call it `prueba.tex`, for example), and compile it: `\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{anteproyectoTabularX} 
\nocite{*}

\end{document}` Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes Sir. I've found it. I was putting a biblatex entry for article in the .bib file instead of a bibtex entry and I'm using bibtex for my references. That almost drove me to craziness. By the way, which do you prefer: bibtex or biblatex?

Comment: @jd1215 I'm glad to hear the culprit was found. Regarding your question, if you are free to choose, I'd go with `biblatex`; it has a lot of features that `BibTeX` is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21356/discussion-between-jd1215-and-gonzalo-medina).